# WebRtc server for making a video conference app in flutter that scales well

Tags: flutter, webrtc, jitsi, mediasoup, livekit

I am trying to make a video conference call app in Flutter app with web support. I don't want to use videoSDK like Agora.

I found some open-source SFU servers such as Livekit, Jitsi and mediasoup. I am not sure which one to use. I want to know which of them or any other SFU serves that provides good developer experience and has easier learning curve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All of the servers that you describe are high-quality SFUs, and you will probably be happy whichever you choose.  There are some differences, though:

- Jitsi is great, but it's a little bit too complex for many needs, and requires a fair amount of infrastructure (JRE, XMPP); I don't recommend it if you want to develop your own client;
- Livekit is a commercial fork of ion-sfu; its main advantage is the large number of client libraries available (browser, Android, iOS); it has some minor technical issues (like poor audio-video synchronisation), but should work well for most applications;
- Mediasoup has good reputation, but I haven't looked at it myself.  It provides a client library.

There are some other well-done servers:

- [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) is a fast and lightweight SFU written in C++ with no dependencies; it ships with a JS client library, and is extremely flexible due to its plugin system;
- [Galene](https://galene.org) is a fast and lightweight SFU written in Go; [the protocol is well documented](https://galene.org/README.PROTOCOL.html), and there is a [client library](https://galene.org/README.FRONTEND.html) (disclaimer, I'm the main author).